# UIWebView doesn't scroll when embedded in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I have an UIScrollView which contains 3 UIWebview. The problem is that my webview no more scroll on touch.

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks

Thierry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIWebView implements scrolling internally, so its own scrolling conflicts with the scrolling of the UIScrollView that contains it.

A possible solution to this could be to resize webviews to fully contain their content, similar to how webviews resize the frames in a frameset.

Comment: This is correct.  Scrolling is a flick-gesture and according to the developer doc, UIWebView cannot be subclassed.  I am using UIWebView for a credits page and want to autoscroll (like movie credits). I'll let you know how I solve.

Answer (score 2):

You may have not set the delegate of the `UIScrollView` to the main `UIWebViewController`. Add your view controller class.

Answer (score 0):

You may have not set the delegate of the UIScrollView to the main UIWebViewController. Add:

```
[scroll setDelegate:self];
```

And in the .h add:

```
... : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```